# Handle shell script in git that changes the branch

Tags: git, shell

I have a shell script in my git repo to handle my release

in summery it does the following

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout master
git pull

Calculate next version

git merge develop 
run script to apply version
git add
git commit
git push

git checkout develop
git merge master
scripts to prepare for the new develop version
git add
git commit
git push
```

This script works fine, as long as I don't make changes in it, as soon as I change the script it breaks, and then I need to merge develop manually back into master. from that point on it works again

Is there a way to run this script after an update without having to manually merge it in both develop and master?

Comment: You can look at [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) but a proper build automation tool or continuous integration software is probably better.

Comment: Githooks is not really what I need, and build/integration tools are used further down the chain, this script handles stuff like, setting the version correctly in all files, generate release notes, etc etc, the actual build will happen on a build server, but the script itself relays on user input